# Font size of text is increasing when the line wraps

Tags: html, css

So I have some text on a page I'm working on, and whenever the text gets too long and needs to wrap, it also increases the font size by nearly 200%. Even weirder is the fact that it only does this when the text needs to wrap onto a third line. At two lines, it still works properly. I'm testing this in Chrome v43.0.2357.81 in device mode to emulate a phone. It also only does this in device mode. I've looked through all my code, all my CSS rules, and I can't find what's causing this.

Here's what it looks like when the text is no more than two lines.

[image]

The computed value for font-size is 25px here, which is what it's supposed to be.

After adding another "blah" to make it wrap

[image]

And now the font-size is `46.9195327758789px`.

The line-height also stays the same, when it's set to be a multiple of the font-size. It still stays at `1.4 * 25px`, instead of `1.4 * 46.9px`.

Here is the CSS rules for the div the text resides in.

```
display: inline-block;
width: 90%;
height: auto;
background-color: #989879;
color: white;
font-size: 25px;
border: 1px solid white;
border-left-style: none;
border-right-style: none;
padding: 6px;
```

Comment: can you show your css/ and/or reproduce in a jsfiddle

Comment: try to use  `-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to fix it. Apparently it was because of setting height to auto. Setting it to 100% made it stop adjusting the size of the div and by extension, the text.